# Sublimetext2 Installation on Mac OS X 10.7.4

Tags: installation, osx-lion, sublimetext

I am trying to install SBT2 and have following setting

**OS**

**Mac OS X 10.7**

```
tbc:~ mystic$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
tbc:~ mystic$ python -V
Python 2.7.2
```

I downloaded the dmg package from SBT2 website and install it but I get an error after I opened the SBT2 application

```
Unable to run package setup:

Failed to load module

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./PackageSetup.py", line 7, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/zipfile.py", line 4, in <module>
    import struct, os, time, sys, shutil
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/struct.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _struct import *
ImportError: No module named _struct
```

What more I tried according to sublimetext2 forum help

```
tbc:~ mystic$ ls -la /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 5 root admin 170 Jun 12 2011 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root admin 204 Jun 12 2011 ..
drwxrwxr-x 11 root admin 374 Jun 12 2011 2.7
drwxrwxr-x 10 root admin 340 Jun 9 2011 3.0
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root admin 3 Sep 25 2011 Current -> 2.7
tbc:~ mystic$ cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
tbc:Versions mystic$ sudo rm Current
Password:
tbc:Versions mystic$ sudo ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7 Current
```

As I have Python2.7 as its default I dont know why SBT2 is going after Python2.6

It shouldn't been this complicated I know, but running out of ideas to make it work.

Any help and suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I meet same issue. After spend a lot time to dig into its configuration file or plist, i get nothing.

Then I find some tips to cheat Sublime Text 2 to use python 2.7 instead 2.6

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
sudo mv 2.6 2.6-backup
sudo ln -s 2.7 2.6
```

And this works for me.

Comment: Any luck? Any question, let me know.

Comment: ln -s 2.7 2.6 Permission denied

Comment: You need use sudo to run it. 
"sudo ln -s 2.7 2.6"