# Sublime crashing on open, no suitable python image found, architecture

Tags: architecture, 32bit-64bit, uninstallation, crash-reports, sublimetext2

I tried to re-open sublime after force quitting it. I followed [instructions to return sublime to an earlier state](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/revert.html) but I had no data folder, so in an attempt to uninstall, I deleted and permanently removed everything with sublime in it. Is there any way I can uninstall sublime besides via the instructions on the "revert" page? Or change my python versioning so that sublime starts working?

I also looked up other "no suitable image found" errors, and it seems like the architecture might be a problem (I recently updated python using homebrew and I'm on Lion, so maybe its some 32/64 bit problem?) I also tried re-installing the most recent version of python.

The error report I get on opening is printed below.

```
Process: Sublime Text 2 [1088]
Path: /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2
Identifier: com.sublimetext.2
Version: Version 2.0.1, Build 2217 (2217)
Code Type: X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [210]

Date/Time: 2012-08-13 23:42:36.059 -0400
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.7.4 (11E53)
Report Version: 9

Interval Since Last Report: 755530 sec
Crashes Since Last Report: 31
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report: 7
Anonymous UUID: 48A0DEC5-738E-472E-A106-15F5341FFA5B

Crashed Thread: 0

Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python
Referenced from: /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2
Reason: no suitable image found. Did find:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python: stat() failed with errno=13
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Python: stat() failed with errno=13

Binary Images:
0x10f292000 - 0x10f842fef +com.sublimetext.2 (Version 2.0.1, Build 2217 - 2217) <EFE756CA-FF0C-3EEB-BA80-309F00040A5D> /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime Text 2
0x7fff6ee92000 - 0x7fff6eec6baf dyld (195.6 - ???) <0CD1B35B-A28F-32DA-B72E-452EAD609613> /usr/lib/dyld
0x7fff89f86000 - 0x7fff89f86fff com.apple.Carbon (153 - 153) <895C2BF2-1666-3A59-A669-311B1F4F368B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon
0x7fff9349a000 - 0x7fff9349afff com.apple.Cocoa (6.6 - ???) <021D4214-9C23-3CD8-AFB2-F331697A4508> /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa

Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.3 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.68f96
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 384 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.4.20)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.5f11, 2 service, 11 devices, 4 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545032B9A302, 320.07 GB
Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5970H
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424 (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 5
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0252, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424 (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Thanks in advance

PBadger

### Update

So it turned out I needed to change the version of python sublime was targeting. To do this I followed [Sublimetext2 Installation on Mac OS X 10.7.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037934/sublimetext2-installation-on-mac-os-x-10-7-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you had remove python 2.6 or Python.framework.

So,you can install Python.

if  you install python from sources please pass enable framework args

```
./configure --enable-framework=/Users/ronald/Library/Frameworks
```

if still tip the error, it may be Python version problem.

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
sudo mv 2.6 2.6-backup`
sudo ln -s 2.7 2.6
```

Above code can make a soft link shared Python version between 2.6 and 2.7.

Then issues solved.

It works for me .